# I try to upload images and input text field to ASP Net Core Web API but controller not read (Angular 13, NET 5)

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0, angular13

I need to upload product details and product images into ASP.NET core web API. I implement HTML files as below

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
            <mat-card>
                <h2 class="fw-bold text-center">Product Management</h2>
                <label class="fw-bold" for="">Product Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" formControlName="ProductName" class="form-control">

                <input type="text" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Product Description" class="form-control mt-3 mb-2" formControlName="ProductDescription">
                <input type="text" name="price" id="price" placeholder="Product Price" class="form-control mt-3 mb-2"  formControlName="price">
                <input type="text" name="created" id="created" placeholder="Product created" class="form-control mt-3 mb-2"  formControlName="created">
                <input type="text" name="cat" id="cat" placeholder="Product created" class="form-control mt-3 mb-2"  formControlName="ProductCatID">

                <input type="file" name="Image" id="Image" class="form-control mt-3 mb-2" (change)="onFileChange($event)" formControlName="ImageUrl">
                <img [src]="imageSrc" *ngIf="imageSrc" style="height: 300px; width:500px">

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-3">Submit</button>
            </mat-card>
        </form>
```

This is TS file i have implement for the submit data

```
submit(){
console.log(this.myForm.value);
this.http.post('https://localhost:5001/api/Products', this.myForm.value)
.subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
  alert('Uploaded Successfully.');
})
```

}

I have implemented Controller As bellow. this controller not read

```
 [HttpPost]
   public async Task<ActionResult<ProductDto>> CreateProductAsync(CreateProductDto pro, IFormFile Image)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Image == null || Image.Length == 0)
            {
                return Content("File not selected");
            }

            var path = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "wwwroot//images", Image.FileName);
            //Saving the image in that folder 
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await Image.CopyToAsync(stream);
                stream.Close();
            }

            pro.ImageUrl = Image.FileName;

            var productEntity = _mapper.Map<Product>(pro);
            var newProduct = _SqlService.AddProduct(productEntity);

            var productForReturn = _mapper.Map<ProductDto>(newProduct);

            return CreatedAtRoute("GetProduct", new { id = productForReturn.ProId },
                productForReturn);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex}");
        }
        
    }
```

Folder Structure
[image]

**I need to upload images into the web API folder and as well as I need store the image and product details in SQL Database**

Comment: The way you are passing the `from value` is not correct. Do you want to submit in formData fashion?